# mongod goes out of memory and crashes after every few hours

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

mongod is running on a dedicated server with mmapv1 storage engine, and it's memory usage keeps on increasing all the time, and finally crashes. Once it's restarted, the db is up again. This keeps on happening in a loop. What might be the cause, and how can it be stopped?

P.S.
i) Mongo is running as a replica-set.
ii) Using mongoengine with pymongo 3.x with django 1.8.x

Attachments:
i) [db.serverStatus()](http://pastebin.com/ekdkCHbp)
ii) [db.stats()](http://pastebin.com/De0jy2mJ)

Comment: You'd better ask this question on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/). StackOverflow is about programming

Comment: you didn't give complete details of your mongod. How much is your working data-set, RAM? Does your mongoengine firing too many sort, order by, mapreduce, aggregation and count queries? Are you seeing any OOM errors in mongod logs?

Comment: Please find the output of db.serverStatus() ad db.stats() above.

Comment: mongoengine is firing a lot of sort, order by, aggregation and count queries.
Yes out of memory in logs in seen. It's looks like this http://pastebin.com/XWHjYVg2